# BufferedReader causing Java GUI to hang

Tags: java, swing, bufferedreader

I am currently working on an add-on to a rhythm game called osu! using Java. There are multiple windows involved, but after the actionPerformed event listener is invoked for one of them, it creates another window that creates an object the constructor of which calls two methods that each use a BufferedReader. However, once I click the button for the actionPerformed, the program hangs and freezes until it is terminated from task manager. Here is the actionPerformed code for the GUI window:

```
private void btnCreateActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) throws IOException {
    String text = textBeats.getText();
    if (text == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Please enter a positive number.");
    }
    boolean isNumber = true;

    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            isNumber = false;
        } else if (c == '-') {
            isNumber = false;
        }
    }

    if (isNumber) {
        double beats = Double.parseDouble(text);
        WindowCode window = new WindowCode(drawArea, file, beats);
        window.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Please enter a positive number.");
    }

}
```

And here are the two methods called when creating WindowCode:

```
public double[] getLastTimingPoint() {
    String line;
    String timings[] = new String[8]; 
    double pointElements[] = new double[8];
    boolean isTiming = false;

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(osuFile), "UTF-8"))){
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("[TimingPoints]")) {
                isTiming = true;
            } else if (line.contains("[Colours]") || line.contains("[HitObjects]")) {
                isTiming = false;
            }
            if (isTiming) {
                if (!line.contains("[TimingPoints]") && !line.contains("[Colours]") && !line.contains("[HitObjects]") && line.length() > 0) {
                    timings = line.split(",");
                }
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < timings.length; i++) {
        pointElements[i] = Double.parseDouble(timings[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("1");
    return pointElements;
}

public double[] getLastInheritedPoint() {
    String line;
    String timings[] = new String[8];
    double pointElements[] = new double[8];
    boolean isTiming = false;

    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(osuFile), "UTF-8"))) {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains("[TimingPoints]")) {
                isTiming = true;
            }
            while (isTiming) {
                if (!line.contains("[TimingPoints]") && !line.contains("[Colours]") && !line.contains("-")) {
                    timings = line.split(",");
                }
            }
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < timings.length; i++) {
        pointElements[i] = Double.parseDouble(timings[i]);
    }

    System.out.println("2");
    return pointElements;
}
```

I have tried to print out checkpoint numbers and it only prints "1" to the console, leading me to believe that it is the second method that is causing this. My question is if the BufferedReader affects the EDT somehow and if it does, how I should get around it.

Comment: Have you tried taking a thread dump using jstack? I will give the details of all waiting threads including those that are in the waiting state including the stacktrace. It might help to identify the root cause

Comment: 1) Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a230513%20BufferedReader%20SwingWorker).

Answer (score 1):

On the second method you have this inner loop:

```
        while (isTiming) {
            if (!line.contains("[TimingPoints]") && !line.contains("[Colours]") && !line.contains("-")) {
                timings = line.split(",");
            }
        }
```

If the file being read contains this string "[TimingPoints]" then variable isTiming will be set to true, and no one else resets it back to false, being trapped into an infinite loop.

You should revise that loop logic.

Comment: Ah I didn't notice that. Thanks, but even after I added an else if statement in the while loop to make sure that it'll be false, I'm still getting the swing hang

Comment: If you add an else, you should reset the flag. Otherwise it will get stuck on that loop forever. If the answer has helped you, please mark it as accepted.